# Swift Playground Import CreateMLUI failure Xcode 12.4 BigSur

Tags: swift, swift-playground, macos-big-sur, createmlui

This has been a problem for people for at least two years, but the old suggestions/fixes do not apply now. I am trying to import CreateMLUI into a playground. It fails. I am using Xcode 12.4 Release (12D4e) on Big Sur 11.1 and the playground is set to MacOS. No Joy!  Saved & resaved play file to no avail. Suggestions?
[image]

Comment: The same problem. I have asked here also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672751

Comment: I also asked in the Dev Forum, but StackOverflow is a far more likely source of info!  ;).           https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672656

Answer (score 0):

`CreateMLUI` seems to be deprecated in favour of [`Create ML`](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/create-ml/) app.

Comment: Indeed! Sadly, while I use Create ML on a weekly basis, it is still not caught up in features to the playground module.